# Not able to add scripts in layout.ejs (sails.js)

Tags: javascript, sails.js, sails-mongo, sails.io.js

I am trying to add a route.js file in the layout.ejs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="scratchpad">
  <head>
    <title>Scratchpad</title>

    <!-- Viewport mobile tag for sensible mobile support -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">


    <!--
        Stylesheets and Preprocessors
        ==============================

        You can always bring in CSS files manually with `<link>` tags, or asynchronously
        using a solution like AMD (RequireJS).  Or, if you like, you can take advantage
        of Sails' conventional asset pipeline (boilerplate Gruntfile).

        By default, stylesheets from your `assets/styles` folder are included
        here automatically (between STYLES and STYLES END). Both CSS (.css) and LESS (.less)
        are supported. In production, your styles will be minified and concatenated into
        a single file.

        To customize any part of the built-in behavior, just edit `tasks/pipeline.js`.
        For example, here are a few things you could do:

            + Change the order of your CSS files
            + Import stylesheets from other directories
            + Use a different or additional preprocessor, like SASS, SCSS or Stylus
    -->
    <!--Twitter Bootstrap-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!--Twitter Bootstrap END-->
    <!--STYLES-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/border.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/tablerow.css">
    <!--STYLES END-->
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class = "navbar navbar-default" role = "navigation">
      <div class = "container-fluid">
        <div class = "navbar-header">
          <a class = "navbar-brand" ui-sref = "scratchpad">MY SCRATCHPAD</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </nav>


    <p>hello world</p>

    <div class = "container">
      <div ui-view></div>
    </div>

    <!--SCRIPTS-->
    <script src="/js/dependencies/sails.io.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/dependencies/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/dependencies/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/dependencies/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/dependencies/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/dependencies/bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/dependencies/application.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/dependencies/route.js"></script>

    <!--SCRIPTS END-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Whenever i add this and save it. Its got saved. But when i try to run `sails lift`. The route.js script getting gone and the layout.ejs file changes into old state. Can anyone figure this out? Any idea of what may be the bug? cause of grunt?

Comment: Is your issue that the actual file layout.ejs is changing. Meaning you have go back and re-edit the layout.ejs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as I remember, everything inside

```
 <!--SCRIPTS-->
...

<!--SCRIPTS END-->
```

section is generated by sails. Try just to put your link after , so it will be like

```
<!--SCRIPTS-->
<script src="/js/dependencies/sails.io.js"></script>
<script src="/js/dependencies/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/dependencies/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/dependencies/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/dependencies/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/dependencies/bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script src="/js/dependencies/application.js"></script>   
<!--SCRIPTS END-->
<script src="/js/dependencies/route.js"></script>
```